# Data Type validation in SoapUI

Tags: web-services, soapui, java-metro-framework

I have created Web-Service using Metro as third party web service engine and it is deployed on glassfish. I used premetive data type **int** as argument. When i enter invalid value like String, null then it takes it as default value(0). Is there any way to restrict it? I want to validate it on SoapUI level and show error message.

In Axis2 it is doing automatically but in Metro it is not working. Is there any extra annotation for this? Or any other way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides of your question.

On the one hand you want to validate you requests on SoaUI level. By default they are not validated and are sent to server as is. To enable validation check two boxes in SoapUI Preferences (tab Editor Settings):

- Always validate request messages before they are sent
- Abort invalid requests

In this case SoapUI generates error message and places caret on the XML line with error.

On the other hand you need to validate incoming requests for correctness on the side of web service. Add **@SchemaValidation** annotation from **com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidation** to enable this function for you service. Metro generates SOAP fault message response for a request that doesn't pass validation against XML Schema.